# How to Kill System Thread by Handle/Object in Windows Kernel

Tags: windows, multithreading, kernel, system, windows-kernel

DriverEntry creates thread A.

A thread creates B, C thread.

A waits for B and C to finish.

I want to forcibly terminate C if B only terminates. (Even in the opposite case)

But I could not find a way to kill a thread with Handle or Object.

Is there a way?

Comment: no any way. this is absolute incorrect

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to do here is not "kill a thread", but rather signal that thread to terminate itself. Your main thread can wait for either of the threads to terminate, and if one of them terminates without the other, signal the remaining one to exit by setting an event or something similar.